# Recruiting firm told a company I work at another company, what can I do?

Tags: recruiting

Let me add some context to my question, really I'm just trying to figure out what/if I can take any legal action against this recruitment firm. I was placed at a job that I currently work for, with a recruiting firm. The firm reached out to me recently to consider me for another opportunity, which I decided to explore. I provided them a recent copy of my resume which didn't include the fact that I moonlight for 2 companies to make myself some extra money. They reached out to me for a reference to the company that they placed me with and I told them explicitly "No" and gave them another person to use as reference. Today my bosses boss pulled me into a meeting to discuss it with me, saying that some reputable sources told me that you might be doing work for another company. Is this any sort of grounds for a lawsuit/action?

- Company 1 (Placed as a Full-Time Employee by the Recruiters)
- Company 2 (Currently employed there as moonlight job)
- Company 3 (Potential employment candidate to replace company 2)
  -Employer Reached out for reference to Company 1 which I responded "No"

Comment: Your steam of consciousness is a little hard to follow but it doesn't sound definitive that the recruiter is the one who shared the info. Is moonlighting explicitly disallowed with your current employer? Are they in a position to do anything about it?

Comment: Does your current contract allow you to moonlight or are you doing this against policy?

Comment: There is nothing specifically laid out on a policy for this. Tried to use bullets to explain it a bit.

Comment: @bruglesco there is no doubt about it, the recruitment company talked to this employer specifically to rat me out

Comment: If you are working at two companies which are presumably in the same city, then sooner or later someone was going to talk to someone. It may just be a coincidence that you talked to the recruiter at around the time that it happened.  As with many questions asked on this site, this one is probably much better suited for https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you are considering legal action, you better have proof of "there is no doubt about it, the recruitment company talked to this employer specifically to rat me out"

Comment: What country are you in?  Laws about what information can be revealed to who vary from country to country.  If you're in the US, for example, you probably don't have grounds for a lawsuit.

Comment: @cdkMoose this is for sure my issue, no definitive proof. I have no doubts personally - but without the hard proof.....I know I have no case.

Comment: @DEnumber50 - there's no incentive for a recruiter to "rat you out" - it's better for them if you remain in everyone's good graces. There are many possible explanations for them - if they put your resume in front of someone at Company 3, that person may know someone at either 1 or 2, and may have communicated that you were looking for a job or may have even shared your resume.

Comment: @dwizum I myself am trying to figure out what they could benefit from saying something about me to this employer. Quite frankly it's none of their business, and I am shocked that they would say anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you can prove that you actually *suffered substantial damages* from this *hearsay* (which might or might not have originated from the recruiting firm) I don't think you have much of a legal case.

The recruiters are acting unprofessional by not respecting your wishes, but since they helped you get your job(s) in the first place it sounds very far-fetched to hold anything against them.

However, this is overshadowed by the fact that you are trying to **work three jobs at once**. This might be acceptable in your location, but I can see many employers having objections about it. Most importantly: are you actually capable to perform useful work at any of these workplaces? Does your work contract have any exclusivity or non-competition clauses? If you are doing any kind of intellectual work, it is likely they do - they *are* paying you to be smart, to be *rested* and to bring your best ideas to improve their products and services. They probably *don't* want you putting effort into other endeavors - there's actually a risk you could be fired from your full-time job for disloyalty.

Comment: If I am removed from the position it for sure would be substantial damages, but you are completely correct that I don't have proof of what was said behind closed doors. To correct I wasn't looking for 3rd employment I was looking to replace 1 for another. No non-competes or policies stating that I cannot work for multiple companies, so really they don't have any grounds to fire me. All I can do is sit back and wait.

Comment: @DEnumber50 Where do you work?  Companies in different places have different restrictions on firing you.  If you're in the US, for example, you're almost certainly an at-will employee, meaning that your employer can fire you for any or no reason (except for a short list of invalid reasons that no employer will admit to).

Comment: @DavidThornley you are completely correct, at-will for me. Meaning that I can be fired for any reason without notice.

Comment: In that case, if they fire you, and it wasn't because of something protected by law (this certainly isn't) then no, you have no grounds for a case against them, regardless of who told what to whom.